# VBA Code - how do I make a code run through a cell that is linked to other sheets with formulas?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook.  One sheet one the code I wrote works perfectly.  I added 5 more worksheets to this book since there are multiple times this can be executed.  To make life easier on myself on sheet one I made a "master chart" that holds all the information for all sheets in the book by linking that cell to the master one.  After I updated my code with the appropriate cells in the master chart I keep getting a "type mismatch" error.  It is occurring when the code reaches the first cell that is linked to a cell that has a formula calculating other cells.  Is this something that can be fixed?

Comment: Can you post the code that you have?

Comment: I would but it is extremely long.  I did try just copying the code from sheet I over three times and it worked since all cells were the same from each sheet.  I think I have this working now.  Thank you

Comment: @Lisa Hunt, no problem. FYI, it can be helpful to paste code into GoogleDocs and just share it with your question. That way people can look at your code and it's not taking up all the room on your stack question